# how .Net Task Parallel Library dataflow send message to many clients with not only one cache?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

There is a Server Task, which uses `TPL Dataflow` to send messages to many clients Task.

- Client connects to the server randomly
- Client can send message to server and client can receive message from server

Server use a `BufferBlock<string>` to send message to client, when client connects to the server, it receive message from this `BufferBlock<string>`.

But this `BufferBlock<string>` can cache only one message, and client can't ask for more than one message from server, and client can't set a condition to select which message to receive.

I want a block type, which can cache several messages; and client can read not only one message from this block type, and client can choose which message to receive;

I tried other `TPL Dataflow` block types, but no one has such ability, does `TPL Dataflow` block is not suit for such requirement?

Condition is simple, each message has a timestamp, client just send a timestamp to server, then server return messages that sent after the timestamp.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using SimpleJSON;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace TestHttp
{
    public class HttpServer
    {
        private HttpListener httpListener;
        public Task task;
        public HttpServer()
        {
            var ta = Task.Factory.StartNew(RunHttp);
            task = ta.Result;
        }

        private async Task RunHttp()
        {
            var httpPort = 9090;
            httpListener = new HttpListener();
            httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:"+httpPort+"/");
            httpListener.Start();
            while (httpListener.IsListening)
            {
                var context = await httpListener.GetContextAsync();
                var req = context.Request;
                Handle(context, req);
            }

            httpListener.Stop();
            httpListener.Close();
        }

        private async Task Handle(HttpListenerContext context, HttpListenerRequest req)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(req.RawUrl);

            var resp = await HandleGet(req);
            var buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resp);
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Encoding", "utf-8");
            context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            context.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
            try
            {
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exp.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
            }

        }

        private BufferBlock<string> messages = new BufferBlock<string>();

        private async Task<string> HandleGet(HttpListenerRequest req)
        {
            var r = req.RawUrl.Split('?');
            if (r[0] == "/send")
            {
                await messages.SendAsync(r[1]);
                return "Suc";
            }
            else if(r[0] == "/receive"){
                var timestamp = Convert.ToInt32(r[1]);
                var ret = await messages.ReceiveAsync();
                return ret;
            }
            //Console.WriteLine(r[0]);
            return "Error";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of condition is that? If you can split messages into a small number of groups based on the conditions, you could have a separate block for each group.

Comment: @svick  condition is simple, each message has a timestamp, client just send a timestamp to server, then server return messages that sent after the timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you saying that the [`BufferBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414.aspx) can contain only one value? It's not true, it can contain as many messages as you want to, based on the block creation options and, specifically, [`BoundedCapacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity.aspx) option. Default value for this parameter is `-1`, which stands for unlimited capacity.

So, at the moment the client connects, you can easy get all the messages filtered by the timestamp, and get them back to client. This, maybe, will lead to changing the signature of the result value for the client's request, as you must provide the `TimeStamp` parameter and provide the ability to return the `List<T>` of the messages and not the only one. Without any code we can't say more for this issue.

Comment: i want to keep message in the block, so any client can take any message they want.

Answer (score -1):

I think TPL dataflow block can't meet such requirement.

I Just use a List to hold all messages `List<Message> messages;`

```
struct Message  {
   int id;
   string msg;
}
```

and i need to use a lock or actor model similar mailbox, to handle my client's the request for the `List<Message>`.

Comment: If you have all the clients to connect to **one** list, you'll have bad performance